# How to pass any record (any type) into Delphi xe7 function as parameter?

Tags: delphi, parameter-passing, record, delphi-xe7

I want to define a function that gets an record (in any type) and give us the fields of that as string. My problem is that how can I pass record to function as parameter? How to declare the parameter?

```
Function GetRecordFields(MyRecord: any record type): string
var
  ctx   : TRttiContext;
  t     : TRttiType;
  field : TRttiField;
begin
 result := '';
 ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
 for field in ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(MyRecord)).GetFields do
 begin
   t := field.FieldType;
   result := result + ' | ' + Format('Field : %s : Type : %s',[field.Name,field.FieldType.Name]);
 end;
end;
```

Comment: since you are new here, I will point out that if the answer works, your should click on the "tick" mark beside it, so that others will know that it works (and, since it's Remy, of course it works).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Generics](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Generics_Index), eg:

```
type
  TRecordHlpr<T: record> = class
  public
    class function GetFields(const Rec: T): string;
  end;

function TRecordHlpr<T>.GetFields(const Rec: T): string;
var
  ctx   : TRttiContext;
  t     : TRttiType;
  field : TRttiField;
begin
 Result := '';
 ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
 for field in ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(T)).GetFields do
 begin
   t := field.FieldType;
   Result := Result + ' | ' + Format('Field : %s : Type : %s : Value : %s', [field.Name, field.FieldType.Name, field.GetValue(@Rec).AsString]);
 end;
end;
```

```
type
  TMyRecord = record
    // fields here...
  end;

var
  rec: TMyRecord;
  S: String;
begin
  // fill rec as needed...
  S := TRecordHlpr<TMyRecord>.GetFields(rec);
end;
```

Comment: What about array of records!

Comment: What about it? You asked for the field names and data types of a record type. An array does not change that information. The only reason to pass an *instance* of a record, or an array of *instances*, is if you want to access the field data values, but you did not ask for that.

Comment: OK, your right! I had to ask clearly. How to define a parameter of function to pass any record type to that function? I need values also. Thank you.

Comment: If you need values, you have to pass an instance of the record to the function, and then you can use `TRttiField.GetValue()`.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you Remy for your great answer. Please see my another question here related to this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120136/create-insert-function-of-any-record-type-in-delphi-xe7