# Create insert function of any record type in Delphi XE7?

Tags: delphi, parameter-passing, delphi-xe

I have an record type for each Table in SQL Server. So when I want to insert (or update) a record on table I define a function to do so. Each field in delphi record has equivalent field in SQL table (with exact same name an type).
  It is too interesting to me to write a function to do this ( for example Inserting) for all record types using Retti. I mean a function that have a parameter for receive any record and creates insert query.
  I searched a lot  and asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232101/how-to-pass-any-record-any-type-into-delphi-xe7-function-as-parameter) question but finally not find the solution. Can anyone guide me to solution. I mean how to pass any record (any type) into a function as parameter?

Comment: From your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232101/), you already know how to pass any arbitrary record type to a function and retrieve the names and values of the fields from it. So making an SQL query from that information should be easy by comparison. What problem are you having with that? What have you tried so far that is not working?

Comment: I do not know how to write function definition. Can you please write it for me? I mean :
     
    public      
       function CreateSQLInsert(.. any record ..)     

How define function param to allow pass any record instance. Really appropriate.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible in Delphi or not?

Comment: The answer to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232101/) showed you **exactly** how to do that.  So what is the problem now?  Asking people to "please write it for me" is not what this site is about. Try it yourself first, then ask for help making it work.

Comment: IMHO you should benefit from using a true ORM instead of building your own. Sounds easy at first but a true fast ORM is a challenge to code and maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
type
  TSqlHlpr<T: record> = class
  public
    class procedure Insert(const Rec: T);
  end;

class procedure TSqlHlpr<T>.Insert(const Rec: T);
var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  RecType: TRttiType;
  TableName: String;
  Field: TRttiField;
  Value: TValue;
  FieldValues: TDictionary<String, TValue>;
  FieldPair: TPair<String, TValue>;
begin
  FieldValues := TDictionary<String, TValue>.Create;
  try
    Ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
    try
      RecType := Ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(T));

      TableName := RecType.Name;
      // massage TableName as needed to match the DB...

      for Field in RecType.GetFields do
      begin
        Value := Field.GetValue(@Rec);
        FieldValues.Add(Field.Name, Value);
      end;
    finally
      Ctx.Free;
    end;

    for FieldPair in FieldValues do
    begin
      // insert FieldPair.Value into FieldPair.Key column of TableName as needed...
    end;
  finally
    FieldValues.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```
type
  TMyTable = record
    // table fields here...
  end;

var
  rec: TMyTable;
begin
  // fill rec as needed...
  TSqlHlpr<TMyTable>.Insert(rec);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I found my answer. Yes it is possible and so simple using untyped parameters like this :

```
procedure CreateSQLInsert(var Data)
begin
  // and do whatever with your any type record using Retti
end;
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you lose all type information about the parameter. You can't query it with RTTI if you don't know what kind of data it is to begin with. An untyped `var` lets you pass **anything**. And if you do know ahead of time what kind of data is being passed, you shouldn't be using an untyped `var` to pass it.  In this situation, you should be using Generics, like I showed you in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232101/).

Comment: Yes, it is possible, just not the way this answer suggests.  Jse Generics and RTTI instead.